# Proper permissions scheme allowing Z3 to read/write to a directory from Java

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, permissions, z3

I'm working on a project that is written in Java that uses Z3 (http://z3.codeplex.com/).  Basically, Z3 creates a temporary file in a specified directory, uses it, and then deletes it.  Z3 is executed from inside some Java code.  The original permissions for the read/write directory were rwxrwxr_x and the Java code was throwing a FileNotFoundException (Permission denied) exception.  We have changed these permissions to 777 to allow Z3 to run properly.  No exceptions are being thrown now.

I want to know if there is a more proper way to handle this so the directory isn't completely vulnerable with the 777 permissions.  Is there a better permissions scheme to handle this?  Z3 is being executed in a separate thread, if that is useful.

Edit: This code is a web application running on a Tomcat server, which is running on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: This is a web application running on a Tomcat server.  Would the user be Tomcat?

Comment: If that's the user you've created and are executing tomcat under, then yes.